# Do Azure Function output bindings have a retry policy?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions-runtime

Certain Azure Function triggers have a retry policy per docs, but what about output bindings? What if an attempted write to blob via output binding fails? Is there any retry around that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no. Check this issue here at the function github: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/891

There is no explicit error handling, as per the closing comment.

For .net code only the recommendation is:

For the output bindings use (CosmosDb, BlobStorage and TableStorage), when you use IAsyncCollector and call FlushAsync() on the binding, the operation is executed and you are able to catch errors related to that operation.